# BAM Archive activitywindow setting doesn't work

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-bam

We have a job running to do moving the data from BAMPrimaryImport to BAMArchive.After deploying the BAM, we run the following command on the target server (single dev server)

```
bm set-activitywindow -Activity:AnActivity -TimeLength:30 -TimeUnit:Day
```

and get the following response...

```
Microsoft (R) Business Activity Monitoring Utility Version 3.9.469.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Using 'BAMPrimaryImport' BAM Primary Import database on server 'anyserver'...

The online window for activity 'AvaPreValidation' has been successfully set to 30 days.
```

So far it looks all good.  I then executed the BAM_DM_[ActivityName] job to see what happened. The test data I generated on that dev server 5 mins ago is still disappeared from BAMPrimaryImport (moved to BAMArchive).

Can anyone advice please?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have resolved the probelm by myself. The command I mentioned above actually works. I should check the view bma_[activity]*AllInstances rather than table bam*[activity]_completed